# Is it possible to determine the mean of a random variable when it is truncated after being drawn from a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, means, gaussian

Apologies if the title is confusing, allow me to clarify.

Say you have a normal distribution with µ = 50 and σ = 25. A random variable drawn from this distribution would of course have a mean of 50.

But what if this random variable is arbitrarily truncated to certain bounds? For example, if a random value drawn from this distribution were less than zero, it would instead become zero, and likewise, if a random value drawn from this distribution were greater than 75, it would instead become 75. In this scenario, the probability of obtaining a value of exactly zero is

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac1{25\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12(\frac{x-50}{25})^2}\approx0.0227501$$

and the probability of obtaining a value of exactly 75 is

$$\int_{75}^\infty\frac1{25\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12(\frac{x-50}{25})^2}\approx0.158655$$

Is it possible to determine the mean value of a random variable drawn from a distribution when it is truncated in such a way?

Note that I do not mean a [truncated normal distribution](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf), in which there is a 0% chance of selecting a value outside of the truncation range, and the probability of all other values is scaled uniformly to maintain a total integral of 1.

Comment: Yes. You can either re-write the pdf with $d$-function or just compute the integral of the expectation in the limits $\int\limits_0^{75}$ and add $0\Pr(x<0)+75\Pr(X>75)$.

Comment: Thank you, the expectation value function is what I was missing/forgot about. It’s been a bit since I had my math and physics classes.